# Crear un ejecutable en windows de una aplicación kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, exe

Buenas dispongo de una aplicación gráfica hecha en kivy que tiene varios archivos de datos y carpetas que contienen archivos py necesarios para su ejecución. La estructura del programa sería la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito emplear esta estructura. La carpeta data contiene archivos csv necesarios para el programa, la img almacena imagenes que el programa crea y emplea, y la env contiene un entorno virtual con python 3.7.7 y las librerias necesarias para el empleo del programa. La carpeta pruebas sobraría y la scripts por último contiene los scripts que se van llamando desde main.py para ejecutar el programa. 
He intentado realizar el proceso mediante la guia que proponen en la pagina de kivy y el ejecutable que consigo no funciona. Si alguien sabe como se puede realizar esto lo agradecería.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya he conseguido realizar el ejecutable de mi aplicación, el problema estaba en ciertas importaciones que no estaba realizando. Voy a describir un proceso general para que todo el que quiera hacer esto y tenga algún problema pueda solucionarlo.
La guía oficial de Kivy es la siguiente: [Kivy Windows](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html).
 Ahora bien, para realizar el proceso, llevaremos a cabo los siguientes pasos:

1. Debemos crear una carpeta y tener instalado PyInstaller en nuestro python. En mi caso previamente activé el entorno virtual localizado en la carpeta env e instalé en él esta librería. Para evitar un posible problema que surge a veces, es recomendable instalar la librería directamente desde github mediante el siguiente comando:

   > **pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip**
2. Una vez hecho esto desde nuestro entorno virtual o python, debemos situarnos en la carpeta en la que queremos el ejecutable y ejecutar el siguiente comando:

   > **python -m PyInstaller --name NOMBRE_APLICACION ruta\del\ARCHIVO_PRINCIPAL.py**
3. Este proceso creará en nuestra carpeta dos subdirectorios, uno llamado build y otro dist, además de un archivo NOMBRE_APLICACION.spec que debemos modificar para que funcione correctamente el proceso.
4. En este archivo "spec" debemos primero importar las librerías que hayamos usado en nuestra aplicación, además, resulta necesario importar para kivy la siguientes librerías:

   > **from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew**

   Y para hacer que funcionen estas librerías en el apartado "coll" que nos creará en este archivo spec, debemos añadir la instrucción "Tree()":

```
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('C:\\RUTA\\APLICACION\\'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='touchtracer')
```

la linea `*[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)]`, también es   necesaria para el correcto funcionamiento.

5. Por ultimo sobre este archivo, en mi caso encontre un error al ejecutar proveniente de que no tenía las librerías `import pkg_resources.py2_warn` y `import pkg_resources`. Además encontré otros dos errores, ya que habia librerías que era necesário añadir a los hiddenimports de la siguiente manera: `hiddenimports=['pkg_resources.py2_warn','win32timezone']`. Averigüé esto gracias a un consejo que me dieron en Reddit, que es ejecutar el exe mediante la terminal, de esta manera podemos ver cuales son los errores que van surgiendo e intentar solucionarlos.
6. Por último para completar el procedimiento hay que ejecutar el siguiente comando:

   > **python -m PyInstaller NOMBRE_APLICACION.spec**

   Haciendo referencia a nuestro archivo spec. Tras completar el proceso, nuestra aplicación debería funcionar correctamente.

Para finalizar, aconsejo tener en cuenta cómo se refieren en el programa a las rutas si necesitase llamar a algún archivo concreto, ya que si usa rutas relativas encontrará problemas a la hora de ejecutar el exe lanzando éste numerosos errores. Puede ver cómo gestionar estas rutas en python usando las librerías os y sys [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python).

Espero que le sea de ayuda a quién intente realizar este proceso y encuentre algún problema. Por último dejo el código de mi archivo spec por si alguien lo necesitase:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.actionbar import ActionBar
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooser
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock, mainthread
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import threading
import os
import sys
import pkg_resources.py2_warn
import pkg_resources

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\dpm24\\Desktop\\StatisticAnalisis - copia\\main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\dpm24\\Desktop\\statistic'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['pkg_resources.py2_warn','win32timezone'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='ejecutable',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,Tree('C:\\Users\\dpm24\\Desktop\\StatisticAnalisis - copia'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)], 
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='ejecutable')
```